# Build Error in Pantheios c++ logger on Windows

Tags: visual-c++, logging, pantheios

when I compile the pantheios library, I get the following error :

error C2664: ‘xtests::c::xtests_startRunner’ : cannot convert parameter 1 from ‘con
st pan_char_t [25]‘ to ‘const char *’
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-
style cast or function-style cast
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC
\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Any idea where it could come from?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think that error only happens in 'Test' section, so build except that.

I'm using vs2010, Windows 7 32bit and got same error. After some googling, this is what I found:

`nmake build.libs`

if you look at the makefile then you'll find more build options and details.

thanks,

jake.

Answer (score 0):

It is [known issue](http://sourceforge.net/p/pantheios/bugs/212/). You could fix it locally as I suggested. Or wait for the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when compiling pantheios-1.0.1-beta214 with Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt.

To add further to Jake and Sergey's comments. The issue is caused by

> pantheios-1.0.1-beta214\test\unit\test.unit.util.onbailout\test.unit.util.onbailout.cpp

```
if(XTESTS_START_RUNNER(PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY, verbosity))
```

XTESTS_START_RUNNER is expecting 'const char*' as first argument. 
PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY is defined as PAN_CHAR_T const

This throws "Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'con st pan_char_t [25]' to 'const char *'.

The work around is to modify the parameter passed to XTESTS_START_RUNNER.

Change 'test.unit.util.gethostname.cpp' line 184 to:

```
if(XTESTS_START_RUNNER("test.unit.util.onbailout", verbosity))
```

This is similar to what is done in test.unit.util.gethostname.cpp

Run 'nmake build' to recompile. After this run 'nmake test'. If you get no errors, pantheios is ready for you to use.